# How to sort a List<User> based on 2 conditions?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list:

```
List<User> users = getUsers();
```

The User object has 2 properties I want to sort by:

```
IsActive
Name
```

Sort first sort by IsActive, and then sort by name.

So the Active Users will be on the top of the list, sorted by name.  Then all the in-active users will be listed (sorted alphabetically).

Is this possible or do I have to break the list up and then merge them?

*There are less than 100 items in this List, so performance isn't really an issue.*

Comment: Another possibility you might want to consider is doing `GroupBy` for `IsActive`, especially if you want to perform some logic for only active users.

Comment: Why the negative votes? It's a valid question in my opinion.

Comment: @Audrius It is valid, but it is not properly researched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Generic list on two or more values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869438/sort-generic-list-on-two-or-more-values)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`. Thanks to Tim Schmelter for his remark. If you use `OrderBy`, you will get the user with `IsActive == false` at the top of your list.

```
var users = getUsers().
    OrderByDescending(u => u.IsActive).
    ThenBy(u => u.Name).
    ToList();
```

Remember to add to your `using` directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: You need `OrderByDescending` instead. Otherwise OP will get inactive first (_"the Active Users will be on the top of the list,..."_).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, is the 'ThenBy' sorting the entire list again?

Comment: @user1361315 No, its exact purpose is to sort only the subgroups of the first ordering. Could you show us the code you're using? [This](http://eve.cx/paste/VVIWK89b.txt) example works fine.

Comment: sorry, it was javascript that was re-sorting on the UI, it did work!

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = users.OrderByDescending(z => z.IsActive).ThenBy(z => z.Name);
```