# How to make an alphabetic list sorter in VB

Tags: vb.net, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I would like to create an alphabetic sorter on Vb. I want the user to be able to type things into a textbox and then sort them alphabetically in another label. I am not fully sure how to do this.

Comment: What did you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried watching a video that told me to use arrays but didn't allow the user to type in their own words.

Answer (score 1):

The List type has a useful subroutine called Sort that will sort your List either by a default sorting order or with a custom one.
Or sort with lambda.

```
    Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim l As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    l.Add("mississippi")
    l.Add("indus")
    l.Add("danube")
    l.Add("nile")

    ' Sort using lambda expression.
    l.Sort(Function(elementA As String, elementB As String)
               Return elementA.Length.CompareTo(elementB.Length)
           End Function)

    For Each element As String In l
        Console.WriteLine(element)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Module

[In Detail - Lamda for multicolumn list sort example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869438/sort-generic-list-on-two-or-more-values)